# Issues registering my application API on google OAuth 2.0

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-drive-realtime-api, owncloud

I am trying to add an google drive account using google api's to Owncloud, but following the instructions in http://doc.owncloud.org/server/5.0/admin_manual/configuration/custom_mount_config_gui.html 
always fails

I have tried 
https://bytenix.net/owncloud/index.php/settings/personal or the same on http

as the Web Origin but i always get "Error
Invalid web origin." on the Google cloud console page. The same applies for the destination, if i try using bytenix.net with https or http as Origin and works fine, but that is not what i want obviously. So what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be because there are two options, 'Web Origins' and 'Authorised Redirect URLs'.

- The 'Web Origins' is for the domain name e.g google.com.
- The 'Authorised Redirect URLs' are the completed path (domain name
  included) e.g. google.com/redirect/to/this/path

Comment: Thanks! I had those two fields mixed up.

Comment: This worked for me, thank you. I kept adding a path to the origin.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for replying to an old post, but you can try solution (for localhost) described here:
https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/javascript

It should works fine, at least in my case did.

Comment: Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. [read more](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)